# How to replace a text cell with image in mvc c#

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

```
<tbody id="chartTable">
     @foreach (Chart item in Model)
     {
         <tr id="tableBody">
              <td>@item.Description </td>
              <td>@item.Type </td>
              <td>@item.Chart </td>
          </tr>
     }
</tbody>
```

I want to replace the above "item.chart" which is text with an image. so if the value of item.chart == bar then barchart icon/image should be show or if pie than image of pie chart will be shown. i have the images but dont know how to do it. I am using JQuery in MVC 3 with razor. thanks

Comment: Is the question is on how to show a bar/pie/chart or is on how to decide which one to show?

Comment: question is if the item.chart is pie then show image of pie in the same cell, if bar then show image of bar in the cell. hope you understand now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
<td>
    @switch (item.Chart)
    {
        case "bar":
            @Html.Raw("<img src=\"barchart_icon.png\" alt=\"bar chart\" />")
            break;
        case "pie":
            @Html.Raw("<img src=\"piechart_icon.png\" alt=\"pie chart\" />")
            break;
    }
</td>
```